# function of void type returning pointers

Tags: c

i am new to programming...the book i am reading has the code below...but it didnt explain it....my question is how is the function`void(*s)()` different from `void *s()`

```
void show();
main()
{
    void (*s)();
    s=show;
    (*s)();
}


void show()
{
    printf("something");
}
```

if i replace `void(*s)()` with `void *s()` a compile time error occurs saying`error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment|`
at the line`s=show;`
and also if i replace `show` with `show()`  runtime error occurs.
can anyone tell me why??

Comment: you need the () around *s when declaring a function pointer (ortherwise, just pointer), and for show != show (), this is because by doing ```s = show``` you assign the adress of show () to the pointer. If you were to do ```show ()```, you would  do nothing more than calling the function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: `(*s)()` is more commonly written as `s()`

Comment: `void(*s)()`==> s is a pointer ...; `void *s()`==> s is a function ...

Comment: Quote: " i replace show with show() runtime error occurs" Hmm, sure about that? It should generate a compile error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [c's operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

```
void(*s)();
```

Reads as: define a variable `s` that if it gets dereferenced and then called *gives* a void. Thus s is a pointer to a function.

```
void *s();
```

Reads as: declare a name `s` that if it gets called and then dereferenced *gives* a void. The call operator `()` is evaluated before the dereferencing `*`. Thus s is a function. This line would just declare a function s with no arguments and a void pointer as return-value. It's the same as your first line `void show();`. Just with a different name and a different return-value.

**Functions can not be assigned**

You obviously know, that functions are defined by appending a body `{...}`.
Function pointers, as any other pointer, can be assigned.
This is the reason why you get the compiler error `lvalue required as left operand of assignment`. It says: "I am not allowed to assign to the left side of the `=`"

Let's look at the code:

```
s=show;
```

is the short form of `s = &show;` => assign the address of the function show to the pointer s.

```
(*s)();
```

Dereference the pointer s and then call it. Which can be shortened to `s();`

In addition:
`void(*s)();` is a **definition** it actually creates a variable, thus you can assign a value to it.
`void *s();` is a **declaration** it just tells the compiler that an element named `s` exists wihtout creating it. Since no variable is created you can not assign to it.

Answer (score 1):

`void (*s)()` and `void* s` are very different things. The first is a pointer to a *function* returning void (notice the round braces after the declaration), the second one is just a plain pointer to untyped data.

Think of the first pair of braces as a reading hint. "s is a pointer to a function returning void" instead of "s is a pointer to void"

Comment: Seems to me that you misread the question. OP is not replacing `void (*s)();` with `void *s;` Instead OP is replacing `void (*s)();` with `void *s();`

Answer (score 1):

To know the difference between the `void (*s)();` and `void * s();` you need to know how the compiler read declarations .

The compiler read the declaration as:

1. start from the identifier
2. move reading the declaration to the right forward until facing the right regular brace ")" or the end of the declaration
3. change the direction of reading the declaration to the left until facing the left regular brackets "(" or the end of the declaration
4. repeat from step number 2 if the declaration is not finished

so, applying these points to the two declarations:

- `void (*s)();`

  1. **s is a**
  2. nothing after the identifier because we faced ")"
  3. **pointer to**
  4. repeating number 2 we will face a **function that has no info about what it receives**
  5. repeating number 3 after the right is finished **and return void**

read the **bold** it will be: **s is a pointer to function that has no info about what it receives and return void**
 - `void * s();`
 1. **s is a**
 2. **function that has no info about what it receives** the right dir is finished here
 3. **and return a pointer to void** the left dir is finished here
 4. the declaration is finished

read the **bold** it will be: **s is a function that function that has no info about what it receives and return a pointer to void**

Now let's answer you questions:

> if i replace void(*s)() with void *s() a compile time error occurs sayingerror: lvalue required as left operand of assignment| at the lines=show;

as we discussed the `void *s();` is a **function** not a **function pointer** and you can not assign value to a function name identifier

> and also if i replace show with show() runtime error occurs. can anyone tell me why??

because the assignment operator in `s=show()` need a `rvalue` to be assigned but, you are not returning any values from calling the function `show`.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @pmg comment.

There are a difference between `void s();` and void `s(void);`

- `void s();` is a function that has no information about what it receives.
- `void s(void);` is a function that receive nothing.

*The two functions return `void`*

Comment: @pmg meaning that there is no function parameters or you can say the function receive void

Comment: @pmg yes they are the same

Comment: @pmg Thanks for your comment. This is a new something to me. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @pmg I with you not delete your comment :)